# Retrieving data from excel sheet and represent it in form of combo Box ,list and text Box in C# .net

Tags: c#

I have a Excel sheet with some columns like States ,District Species in forest, Volume Equation(General)and Volume Equation(local).Through this excel sheet i have to design a Windows Form Application in C# so that the states in sheet be represented in combo Box and on selection of states again a drop down combo Box appear to select its districts then list view appears for selection of species and on a click of button the volume equation both general and local appears in textboxes. **Could Anyone Help me out I m just beginner and i was just able to show the whole sheet in datagridview **

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow. Please take some time to read the help page, especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). And more importantly, please read [the Stack Overflow question checklist](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/156810/204922). You might also want to learn about [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Examples](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0):

first you read the Excel file using INTROP library after you can store that data in array after than you read value from array one by one and bind it with your control as per your desire

Comment: Thanks for Your help I will try it and tell the results thanks once again.